# how to sort multi dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, sorting

how to sort multi dimensional array in javascript

```
        how to sort this multi dimensional array in javascript

            var arr = [];
            arr[0]  = [{id:1}, {id:5}, {id:7}];
            arr[1] =  [{id:3}, {id:8}, {id:6}];
            arr[2] = [{id:2}, {id:4}, {id:9}];


            The output should be like this
            arr[0]  = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
            arr[1] =  [{id:4}, {id:5}, {id:6}];
            arr[2] = [{id:7}, {id:8}, {id:9}];
```

Comment: Try to go through this sort documentation http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp  and then ask any problem you encountered.

Comment: Since Javascript's Array object is unidimensional, there's no built-in method to do what you intend. As a matter of fact, you are not sorting, you are moving elements between completely separate array objects.

Answer (score 2):

You will need some helper functions:

```
Array.prototype.flattened = function() {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this);
};
Array.prototype.splitBy = function(n) {
    var r = [];
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; i+=n)
        r.push(this.slice(i, i+n));
    return r;
};
Array.prototype.sortBy = function sortBy(key) {  
if (this[0] && this[0][key] == "number")
        return this.sort(function(a,b) {return a[key] - b[key];});
    return this.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[key]<b[key] ? -1 : a[key]>b[key] ? 1 : 0;
    });
};
```

Then, it is easy:

```
arr.flattened().sortBy("id").splitBy(3);
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/6kXvt/))

Comment: +1, a little dense, but a more generic approach all round. To the OP: read up on the possible consequences of augmenting prototypes, though... not that this code will cause major conflicts, but just know why you shouldn't go _prototype-crazy_ all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* solution I can think of is this:

```
var sortChunks = function(ar, property,chunkSize)
{
    //set default params:
    chunkSize = chunkSize || ar[0].length;// || 3?;
    property = property || 'id';
    var i=0,j=0,all = [],ret = [];
    for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
    {//"map" objects, use property as array index
        for(j=0;j<ar[i].length;j++)
        {
            all[ar[i][j][property]] = ar[i][j];
        }
    }
    all.sort(function(a,b)
    {//move all undefined keys to the end of the array
        if (a === undefined)
            return 1;
        if (b === undefined || b.id > a.id)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    });
    while(all && all[0] !== undefined)
    {//make chunks
       ret.push(all.splice(0,chunkSize));
    }
    return ret;
};
//usage:
arr = sortChunks(arr);//returns desired array
//or
arr = sortChunks(arr,'id',3);
```

Having said that, you're probably better of rethinking the way this array is built, and change that code, rather than relying on this rather meaty (and in its current form rather error-prone) sorting function.

Meanwhile, [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFtVV/) to see it in action... sort of

Answer (score 0):

You can create "1 dimensional" array with n * m elements. where n and m are number of rows and columns. Then use one of sorting algorithms.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm